# Add subview to view so that it overlays the UITabBar but not the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'd like to add an overlay to my current UITableView - so that it overlays the entire table and the UITabBar at the bottom of the screen.  I don't, however, want it to overlay the UINavigationController.

When I try `[self addSubview:]` on the `UITableView`, it does not overlay the UITabBar.

In my storyboard, I have a`UITabBar` and each tab instantiates it's own`UINavigationBar`.  This tab then contains a `UITableView`.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

set y origin of your overlay to 44 and add this overlay to navigation's view

```
[overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(self.overlayView.frame.origin.x, 44, self.overlayView.frame.size.width, self.overlayView.frame.size.height)];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:overlayView];
```

don't forget to add +20 on y origin value when running on iOS7.